# Strange issue starting a node application from another directory

Tags: node.js, express, model-view-controller, pm2

I've got an MVC application using Nodejs / Express.

If I start the app using PM2 within the directory EG.

```
pm2 start my_app.js
```

All is well. If I try to start it from another directory EG.

```
pm2 start ../another_directory/my_app.js
```

The app appears to start fine, but when I browser the app it complains it can't find the view file. The error implies it's looking for the view file in the directory (EG my_folder/views I'm sat in, instead of ./another_directory/views/my_view.

Sorry this is a bit general. But does this ring a bell with anybody please?

Thanks.

Edit.
Would setting a Express namespace solve this issue as per:

[Setting an Express namespace](https://nosleepjavascript.com/express-route-namespace/)

Edit 2.
It didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

If anybody is interested, I solved it by adding the following to my start uo .js script I was calling:

```
app.set('views', `${__dirname}/views`);
```

Seems I had to reinforce the path to the views.